# Why does the definition of constructor make different value

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I'm testing the piece of code below:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    foo() {}
    int a;
};

struct bar
{
    bar();
    int b;
};

bar::bar() = default;

int main()
{
    foo f{};
    bar b{};

    std::cout << f.a << '\t' << b.b << std::endl;
}
```

The output is `0       21946`.

Well, it seems that the object `f` is initialized with Zero initialization but the object `b` is initialized with default initialization. The default initialization of an `int` is a random number and that's why I got a `21946`.

Why did I get two different kinds of initialization here?

I knew that the variable with static storage duration may be initialized with Zero initialization and it put at the `.bss` segment, this is a kind of static initialization. But `foo f{}` is obviously a kind of dynamic initialization. Why is `f` initialized with Zero initialization, instead of default initialization? Why does the compiler make two different behavior?

Comment: Neither `f.a` nor `b.b` are initialized, both contain indeterminate values. Of course such a vaue can be 0.

Comment: Confirming @churill: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d9e445e186e82f1 (see warnings and notice that here, both values happen to be 0)

Comment: @molbdnilo: `constexpr` might help, as initialized at 0 would be ok, whereas uninitialized would fail (ok, it fails before it can be read as 0, but the check for initialization is possible in some circonstance (as `constexpr` has other constraints) :-) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor):

> Defaulted default constructor outside of class definition (the class must contain a declaration (1)). Such constructor is **treated as user-provided**

Therefore, none of the statements are [value-initializations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Both are default initialization because they have user-provided constructors. And the values of non-static data members leaves uninitialized (can contain an arbitrary number, including zero)

To do the value initialization for the defaulted constructor case, use the in-class declaration:

```
struct bar
{
    bar() = default;
    int b;
};
```